# VSCode C++ with WSL: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I want to run C++ code using WSL2 on my Windows 10 machine.

I followed this guide step by step up to this point: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl#_run-helloworldcpp

Clicking on `Run C/C++ File` gives me the error message:

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted\n"
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-o2o5gmaj.nup" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-y3zvkit4.33t"
```

If I click on `Debug C/C++ File` I get the following:

```
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8002509
Cannot insert breakpoint 2.
Cannot access memory at address 0x800279c

The program '/mnt/d/workspace/cpp_tut/hello' has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a).
```

(Note that I've only set one break point in my IDE, I'm not sure where the second one comes from)

The only info I find on this online is that this is supposed to have been fixed in WSL2, but it clearly isn't. For sanity I've checked if g++ is the problem but `g++ ./hello.cpp -o hello` seems to be working fine so I doubt it is.

I have:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64 
Kernel: 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
VSCode 1.86.2
```

Not sure which other info I should provide, thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:**
Did some more experimenting. If I run gdb on the g++ output file myself I get the following:

```
$ gdb ./hello
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x251d: file /mnt/d/workspace/cpp_tut/hello.cpp, line 8.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /mnt/d/workspace/cpp_tut/hello 
warning: opening /proc/PID/mem file for lwp 1887.1887 failed: No such file or directory (2)
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8002509
```

If I look in `/proc/` there is no `PID` directory.

Comment: VSCode is a very advanced, complex development tool that's designed for highly skilled, experienced developers who have a wide range of domain knowledge, like the JSON configuration syntax, and familiarity with obscure compiler flags and options. It is not meant to be used for people who are just starting out learning C++ and who do not have established development experience, those people will find other development environments, like VS community edition (Windows) or emacs+make (Linux, MacOS), easier to use.

Comment: I get the idea this may be some permission issue. If you created the directory in an elevated terminal then vscode doesn't have write access.

Comment: The error looks like [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8516). So you probably need a newer gdb.

Comment: @ssbssa I found some posts by people who fixed it by downgrading gdb. That worked for me too, but just in case I think I'll also try upgrading to a newer version and see if that does it too.

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" the issue by downgrading to GDB 10.2 (Installing it from source)